# Django: 'ModelForm' object has no attribute

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I'm working with Django Forms in order to create a new object, but I'm having problems with it. It all renders OK, but when I submit the Form, an error is raised:

> "AttributeError at /rutinas/nueva_rutina
>
> 'DiaForm' object has no attribute 'ejercicios'"

I've tried many possible solutions I read here, but they didn't work. I think the problem is with the M2M relationship, but it can also be for processing two forms at a time.  Here are my files

**models.py**

```
class Ejercicio(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')
    descripcion = models.TextField(default='')
    gif = models.ImageField(default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre


class Rutina(models.Model):
     id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
     nombre = models.CharField(max_length=30, default='')

def __str__(self):
    return self.nombre

class Dia(models.Model):
    ejercicios = models.ManyToManyField(Ejercicio)
    rutina = models.ForeignKey(Rutina, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**forms.py**

```
class RutinaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Rutina
        fields = '__all__'
        labels = {
            'nombre': _('Nombre')
        }

class DiaForm(forms.ModelForm):
    ejercicios = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Ejercicio.objects.all())
    class Meta:
        model = Dia
        fields = ['ejercicios']
        labels = {
            'ejercicios': _('Ejercicios')
        }
```

**views.py**

```
def nueva_rutina_view(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    form = RutinaForm(request.POST)
    dia_form_1 = DiaForm(request.POST)
    dia_form_2 = DiaForm(request.POST)
    dia_form_3 = DiaForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid() and dia_form_1.is_valid() and dia_form_2.is_valid() and dia_form_3.is_valid():
        rutina = form.save(commit=False)
        dia1 = dia_form_1.save(commit=False)
        dia2 = dia_form_2.save(commit=False)
        dia3 = dia_form_3.save(commit=False)
        rutina.save()
        dia1.rutina = rutina
        dia2.rutina = rutina
        dia3.rutina = rutina
        dia1.ejercicios = dia_form_1.ejercicios
        dia2.ejercicios = dia_form_2.ejercicios
        dia3.ejercicios = dia_form_3.ejercicios
        dia1.save()
        dia2.save()
        dia3.save()
        return redirect(historial_rutinas_view)
else:
    form = RutinaForm()
    dia_form_1 = DiaForm()
    dia_form_2 = DiaForm()
    dia_form_3 = DiaForm()        
return render(request, 'rutinas/nueva-rutina.html', {'form': form, 'dia_form_1': dia_form_1, 'dia_form_2': dia_form_2, 'dia_form_3': dia_form_3})
```

Comment: Why have you done this? `ejercicios` is a field on the form, it is set when you call form.save already.

Comment: If I remove the lines that say "diaN.ejercicios = dia_form_n.ejercicios", the "Rutina" is saved with 3 "dias", but the "dias" objects are empty, and I want them to contain many "ejercicios".